# "Open With" dialog ignores my selection

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7 x64. I have a file type that I want to associate with Microsoft Access 2003.

I right-click on the file and select Open With->Choose Default program. In the "Open With" dialog, I select the browse button. I choose Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office11\msaccess.exe and press "Open".

I end up back at the "Open With" dialog, but nothing has changed. Access is not listed as a program to use to open the file with. The original program (Adobe Acrobat) that is associated with this program is still selected.

Any tips on getting this association to work?

Comment: Yes, this is a bizarre bug that has annoyed me for a long time and several versions of Windows. It only happens intermittently so I have not kept track of which executables exhibit/trigger this behavior, thus I have been unable to find any sort of unique commonality between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't set a program as the default to open a filetype with in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/655600/i-cant-set-a-program-as-the-default-to-open-a-filetype-with-in-windows-7)

Comment: it happens because windows uses only the executable name, not the full path, when storing associations. A full explanation and solution: https://superuser.com/a/886139/425338

Answer (score 51):

The cause is most likely a quirk in the registry that slipped in for some unknown reason.

Make sure the key value in the following location contains the correct path:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\YOURFILE.EXE\shell\open\command
```

Search for the application name and the file extension in the registry to see if other entries are possibly corrupted as well.

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me.. once I changed the value at that exact location, it worked fine as soon as I tried to browse -> open again

Comment: When the key value does not point to the right location of the application, change it as indicated in [another answer here](http://superuser.com/a/559550/245595)

Comment: This fixed it for me.  Problem was I upgraded it from 32-bit to 64-bit, so it was looking in `Program Files (x86)` instead of `Program Files`

Comment: Fixing the path to the app in this registry key fixed it.  It appears when I uninstalled the app, and then reinstalled with a different path, this registry key wasn't updated.  It appears to be a Win7 bug that if the entry for the app exists, windows exits the app selection process without modifying the registry entry; even if the path you select does not match the existing value of the registry entry.  The prevents users from changing the path to an existing app using the "Open with" GUI.

Comment: When I did this, it already showed it in the list, I didn't even have to use "browse". Maybe that's because I tried to select it at its current path before. The regedit key pointed to the location where the program previously was before I moved the folder. I'm pretty sure it was a program that came without an installer (just unzip), but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It helped to fix my problem. Once I corrected the key value. It was OK.

Comment: I had to add both the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\uedit.exe\shell\edit\command and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\uedit.exe\shell\open\command keys manually and then define the name=Default, Type=REG_SZ, value="c:\Program Files\UltraEdit\uedit64.exe" (including the " symbols) for both. After that I was able to specify it as the default opener for txt files.

Comment: Congrats MS.... 6 and half years down the line and we're still doing this.

Comment: Is there any tool to automatically clean these up?  You can manually delete the application entry in FileTypesMan which lets it be re-associated

Comment: This just solved it for me. I finally updated Photoshop from CS3 to CS6, the installer for CS6 fixes the edit command, to point to the new EXE but it doesn't fix the "open" command, had to do that one manually.

Comment: This happened to me after I moved a portable application (VLC) from one folder to another without having de-associating the file extensions first. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

It is a very simple problem, actually. It happens because **Windows uses associations based solely on the base executable name of the program**.

Whenever you associate a program with an extension, the program will be present on the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` list, where the key names are the base names of the executables (e.g., `MSACCESS.EXE` and `AcroRD32.exe`). You can’t associate another program with a file extension if it has the same *executable name*. What happened is that you probably moved the software to another location (you can see it happens mostly with portable software versions) and when you try to point to it, Windows will see that the name is already registered and instead will try to use the registered path. When it can’t find that, it silently ignores the error and presents the dialog back with no changes whatsoever.

The solution is equally simple: just correct or delete the `HKCR\Applications\YourAppName.exe` key and try again. 
It will work.

Comment: It also happens when you have multiple versions of Adobe Photoshop installed (via Creative Cloud) all of which use the same executable name.

Comment: That's it! Very stupid, they should store the path or a hash as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for really explaining what happens! This helped me solve the problem my way. In my case the software was not really moved. The software was just at another path on the local disk because it was another PC in the same company with the same roaming Windows profile ;-)

Answer (score 11):

The registry key shown above was my problem.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MSACCESS.EXE\shell\open\command
```

Should read:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "%1"
```

for access 2010.

It still had the entry:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "%1"
```

for office 2007.

The file does not exist in that location so it did not appear in the application selector until I changed the entry.

Once I updated the registry I was ableto select Microsoft Access directly from the list of available applications.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with Sublime Text. It wouldn't show up in the `Open With` dialog no matter what I did. This is how I solved it.

1. Open `regedit` or any registry editor.
2. Navigate to: `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\sublime_text.exe\shell\open`.
3. Remove **all** the subkeys.
4. Create the subkey `command` with value `"C:\path\to\sublime_text.exe" "%1"` (double    quotes included!).

Of course, this will work with any program, not only Sublime Text. Just replace `sublime_text.exe` with your program's executable.

Answer (score 2):

If all fails, you can edit the registry manually (backup the the hive/key first):

Each file type (extension) which has an associated application has a Registry key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Or use **[FileAsoc](http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/fileasoc.html)**, a Windows File Association Editor

*FileAsoc is open source freeware.*

Or **File Type Doctor**, which is part of the **[Creative Element Power Tools](http://www.creativelement.com/powertools/)** (shareware)

[image]

Comment: They way to change this via registry is indicated in [another answer here](http://superuser.com/a/559550/245595)

Comment: FileAsoc to me doesn't seem a good recommendation, it requires a rather peculiar VB runtime environment (which is not installed by default, and seems hard to come by, the links from FileAsoc's page to these are dead. And the recommended "Creative Element Power Tools" also aren't available anymore!

Comment: Seems this program has fallen off the web. Instead, try FileTypesMan (worked for me): http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem for my wmplayer.exe (that was missing and un-addable in the open with dialogue) by changing the

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications/wmplayer.exe\shell\open\command
```

from

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "%1"
```

to

```
"C:\Programme\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "%1"
```

Where `Programme` is the localized (german) version of 'Program Files'.
This does not make any sense to me (as when i hit "copy path" in the shell menu of windows explorer, the path contains `Program Files`. And when I add the Media Player by browsing in the "open with" dialogue, its also added with `Program Files`), but it worked as a solution, where simply deleting the reg key did not.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen cases where some dialogs don't prompt you for security elevation and do not give you a message that the change could not be made.  Try doing it through control panel

Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Associations

Or just type "file open" into the start menu search and choose "Make a file type always open with a certain program"

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem with all of my media file associations, and it seemed due to an obnoxious media player called DAPlayer. Even under `Control Panel`/`Programs`/`Default Programs`/`Set Default Programs`, I was unable to change the default program. Apparently, it set the `UserChoice` keys under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` for all of its file associations to read-only access, even for administrators. Even after uninstalling the program, all of my associations remained stuck on "Unknown Application".

The simplest way to fix this is to browse to that key in Regedit, right-click it and select Permissions, click the Advanced button, check "Replace all child object permissions", and click OK.

Or if you prefer the command line, you can use a Windows Resource Kit tool called [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510):

```
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f /grant="%USERNAME%"=f
```

**But be careful with bulk registry operations like this: improper use could render your system inoperable!** I take no responsibility for your actions.

Answer (score 0):

NirSoft often rescues: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

That is FileTypesMan (File Types Manager for Windows) by NirSoft.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question. Refer to [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing) for help.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to fix this is deleting all records associated with your desired application

For example:

If the .exe file to be placed at **Open With** list is NOTEPAD++.EXE

1 - Open the **regedit** and find for **notepad++.exe**

2 - Delete all the records found

3 - Now try **Open with** dialog again

... *Bleem!!*