# The program I select through "Open with" > "Browse" does not launch

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Open With” dialog ignores my selection](https://superuser.com/questions/91655/open-with-dialog-ignores-my-selection)

I am using Windows 7. I am using Processing 2.06a and want to start .PDE files with the processing.exe file.
Processing does not have install files (like Eclipse, or any other portable software) so you can place it anywhere. I placed it in the *Program Files* folder however.

If I rightclick on a .PDE file,

click "Open with...",

click "Browse...",

look for the "processing.exe" file,

click "OK" (in the browse dialog)

and click "OK" (in the open with dialog)

it does not open Processing, but it opens Adobe Reader (presumably since it is the first item in the list).

Answer (score 0):

1. After you browse and select processing.exe from the **Browse**
   dialog, please ensure that processing.exe is also selected in the
   **Open With** dialog.
2. Make sure that the following option is checked - 
   **Always use the selected program to open this kind of file**

You have most likely selected Adobe Acrobat reader and made it the default program. You can right click your PDE files and look at the section labeled **Opens with** to identify the default program. To change the default program, click on **change** and click on **browse** and follow steps 1 & 2.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks, this is indeed the normal procedure I am familiar with. However, after selecting the EXE it doesn't appear in the Open With Dialog... so I can't select it there. It's neither under "Recommended Programs" or "Other Programs"

Comment: A quick search seems to indicate that processing.exe is not registered properly. You're required to make a registry edit. The fix is available here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/problems-with-file-association-in-windows-7-64-bit/8a84fcec-22df-4942-8e35-d98dbe96e327