# Can't change Windows 10 default file type association

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-extension, default-settings, sublime-text

After installing [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) on Windows 10, I can not change the default application for files with the `.txt` extension anymore.

Right-clicking on `Context Menu > Open With… > Choose Default Program`, I can select Sublime in the dialog and check "Always use this application." The file is opened once with the chosen application, but the default remains as the Windows Editor.

In the Windows Settings, I am also able to select Sublime in the dialog for `.txt` files, but the file type remains assigned to the Editor.

Things that did not help:

- Restarting
- Checking the registry key in `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\sublime_text\shell\open\command\`
- Uninstalling Sublime Text

[Using ftype](https://superuser.com/questions/841497/windows-open-with-application-not-appearing-as-an-option/1020255) worked, but is unwieldy.

What exactly could have broken the standard file type association dialog? Is it repairable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue [caused by a recent Windows update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462919/windows-10-update-kb4462919), and it is tentatively scheduled to be fixed later this month:

> **Symptom**
>   After installing this update, some users cannot set Win32 program defaults for certain app and file type combinations
>   using the **Open with…** command or **Settings** > **Apps** > **Default apps**.
>
> In some cases, Microsoft Notepad or other Win32 programs cannot be set
>   as the default.
>
> **Workaround**
>   In some cases, attempting to set application defaults again will succeed.
>
> Microsoft is working on a resolution and estimates a solution will be
>   available in late November 2018.

**Sources**:
[October 9, 2018—KB4462919 (OS Build 17134.345)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462919/windows-10-update-kb4462919)
[Microsoft Broke Windows 10’s File Associations With a Botched Update](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/microsoft-broke-windows-10s-file-associations-with-a-botched-update/)

---

## Update

This problem should be resolved with the release of the [KB4467682](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4467682) Windows 10 Quality Update, which will increment the operating system build to 17134.441:

> Addresses an issue that prevents some users from setting Win32 program
>   defaults for certain app and file type combinations using the **Open
>   with…** command or **Settings** > **Apps** > **Default apps**.

**Sources**:
[November 27, 2018—KB4467682 (OS Build 17134.441)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467682/windows-10-update-kb4467682)
[Microsoft Fixes Windows 10’s File Association Bug, Unless You’re Using the October Update](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/microsoft-fixes-windows-10s-file-association-bug-unless-youre-using-the-october-update/)

Comment: Unbelievable. Basic stuff.