# Failed installation of 7zip caused File Extension folders to disappear in Registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, 7-zip

When I tried installing 7zip, an issue occurred that removed a few extensions, most notably .7z and .rar. I'm not really sure what caused the error to begin with.

Due to that error I can no longer associate a program with a file type. Each time I try to open a .7z file, Windows will always ask what program I want to open this with, the selected program runs but the choice will never be saved.

[image]

They were only removed from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, the folder to associate programs still exists from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExts`

I was wondering if anyone has a quick solution to this that I could do myself, if not then my best guess for what to do afterwards is to import from a friend their folders of the missing types.

Comment: I use the [Portable Apps](https://portableapps.com/) version of 7-Zip, which isn't installed in Windows, but is still able under `Tools` -> `Options...` -> `System` to create associations to itself, both for the current user and all users. When 7-Zip is first launched, the `.7z` is not a registered extension, but it is able to create the appropriate entries.

Comment: This may be indicative of the [ongoing problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1374772/changing-default-windows-10-file-type-association-by-standard-dialog/1374778#1374778) related to changing Windows 10 file type associations.  Try installing [KB4467682](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467682/windows-10-update-kb4467682), which supposedly resolves the problem.

Comment: As a wrokaround/alternative, you can create a context menu for specific files to be opened by 7zip.