# How do I associate a filetype to open with a self developed application?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, file-association, code

In .NET/WinForms/C# I wrote a small program for "viewing" PDF files. 
It just opens a real PDF viewer and does some more things (not important for the following problem).

However, under Windows 10 I cannot set my program as the default for opening PDF files.
If I open a PDF file via "Open with..." and select my program and activate the option "Always open with...", next time I open a PDF Windows will use the default PDF viewer again.
In the case that I try to set the default program via the default apps settings, Windows will not even accept my program as a default for PDF files. It only shows other viewers like Acrobat or Chrome.

How can I set my self-coded program to be the default viewer for PDF files?

Comment: Some [similar issues](https://superuser.com/q/1380192/726810). Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1374778/726810).

Answer (score 0):

I believe a combination of assoc and ftype will do the trick.  You run the assoc command to associate an extension to a given ftype.  You run the ftype command to specify what program to run when the given ftype is accessed.

Run

```
assoc /?
```

and

```
ftype /?
```

to get more info.  If they work, I think you can put those commands in your login environment.

Hope this helps.