# Reset default application association in WSA

Tags: windows, android, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-android

I installed [Squid](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/XP890ZMMFFZ34V) from Microsoft Store on Windows 11, this is an Android application and in turn required installing Amazon Store.

Once started the application I clicked on a button that had a `http://` link, Windows asked me what app to use in order to open the link and I selected Google Chrome, the "always use this app" checkbox was already ticked when the dialog popped up.

How can I now reset this default association?

Comment: I would find the registry key responsible and delete it[.](https://superuser.com/questions/841497/windows-open-with-application-not-appearing-as-an-option?rq=1). Provided a link that might be helpful

Comment: I have the same issue with Twitter app.