# Unable to set default program for .cpp file type

Tags: windows-10, notepad, filetype

I'm using the latest edition of Windows 10 Home on a 64-bit computer.

I've been struggling to set the default program used to open .cpp files. At first, it was set to Notepad, but at some point I must have set it to Code::Blocks by accident. I was eventually able to get rid of the association to Code::Blocks, but now .cpp files don't have any association. The best I can do is set them back to Code::Blocks.

I tried many of the suggestions on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/655600/i-cant-set-a-program-as-the-default-to-open-a-filetype-with-in-windows-7) question, but still no luck yet.

I've tried multiple ways of setting the default program: Through the Windows 10 Settings app, the typical "Right click and select Open With", through the Properties window. I even tried NirSoft's [FileTypesMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html). One interesting observation I made is that on the File Types Manager, it does say next to the User Choice option "NOTEPAD.EXE", yet it obviously hasn't worked yet.

I can get through the whole process of setting the program without an error message or anything, yet their is no visible result.

**Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong or what I should try?**

*EDIT*: I have now submitted a problem report in the Windows Feedback Hub. I don't really know if much will happen there, but it will stay there anyways. I'm fine with any discussion continuing here as well :)

Comment: I have the same problem with several Windows 10 software (including notepad+++, 7zip, etc). I think it's a bug in the latest version that should be reported to Microsoft itself. 
This problem is also reported here with texmaker: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457263/138900

Comment: Interesting. I've had a problem with Notepad++, too. I'll try to find a place to report the bug.