# Windows 10 cannot change file associations

Tags: windows-10, file-association, editing

I recently bought a new Windows 10 computer. Installation of my apps without a hitch.

I would like to the default file associations.
For example I would like .GIF to open with Adobe Fireworks and .JPG or .PNG files to open with Photoshop.

Wherever ("File explorer >> Open with" or in the Settings >> apps >> Default apps) I change something it has **NO EFFECT** when I double click on a file with the extension.

Does Windows write a log file somewhere about what goes wrong? I've searched the Event Viewer but found nothing. Perhaps I am searching for the wrong thing?

So far I've tried:

- File Explorer >> "Open with". That only on the one time I click on the menu. Afterwards the default app Photos is active again
- Settings >> Apps >> Default apps by file type or app

Comment: What cumulative update of 1803 do you have installed.  Please edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: This is a known issue with the 1803.  The best way to solve this problem is to report the problem to Microsoft through the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1370796/unable-to-set-default-program-for-cpp-file-type and https://superuser.com/questions/1370592/cant-make-certain-file-associations

Comment: [Solution has been reported that you must revert to 17134.286 which means uninstalling any cumulative update released after the cumulative update associated with 17134.286.](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/9qeijs/cant_set_some_file_associations_properly_anyone/)

Comment: I cant lose the feeling that a directory or file is read only. Perhaps it hs to do with user authorizations in principle. But what?

Comment: The Windows version is: Windows 10 Home 64bit. Version:1803 Build:17134376